# Best way to write a function that takes in a timeout (posix C)

Tags: c, timeout, posix

So I have an embedded Linux device that is connected to a motor controller via a serial port.  I am writing an interface library which makes a lot of nice generic functions which other programs will call.  One of which is a function to run the program that is currently on the controller's flash disk:

```
int run_motor_program(int serial_fd, char *label, timeout);
```

The general pseudocode for this function is:

```
call write(serial_fd, "start program at `label`")
perform a couple read()'s / write()'s to check whether program has started on the motor controller
do
   /* some stuff */
while(program is running AND timeout hasn't exceeded)
If the timeout exceeded, kill motor and return timeout error
```

The timeout in the above function definition is used in case something goes wrong while running the program on the motor controller.  If the motor controller gets stuck in a longer loop than expected, I need the ability to stop program.

The only ways I know for keeping track of a timeout are:

1) Calling gettimeofday() before and during the loop to see if elapsed time is > timeout value passed in

2) Calling clock_gettime() and basically doing the same as 1.

3) Using timer_create() before the loop and timer_getoverrun() in the loop to check if the time has elapsed (this seems to be the most elegant solution, but I can't seem to get timer_getoverrun() to work with SIGEV_NONE [I don't want to use signals]).

Which of these (or if anyone has any other suggestions) is the best way to handle including a timeout in a function?  I really only need resolution down to the millisecond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to do option 1 myself.  If subsecond granularity isn't needed, then I'll use `time`.  Typically the work is checking for IO, so I also use a `select` with a timeout configured.

Comment: Option 1 is what I was thinking.  The problem with `gettimeofday()` and `time()` is that if I (or NTP) changes system time while my function is called, it will screw with the timeout.  For this function, `select()` isn't helpful because I'm not waiting for data on the serial port file descriptor.

Comment: @Ryan: To avoid the NTP problem, use `clock_gettime()` with the `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` clock.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using one of the alarm signal mechanisms.  The simplest and oldest is [`alarm()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/alarm.html), which schedules a SIGALRM signal after the specified number of seconds.  If you have a signal handler for SIGALRM, your process won't die but will allow you to recover from the error.

The primary limitation of `alarm()` is that it deals in whole seconds.  There are a plethora of sub-second or fractional second alternatives.  You should look at `setitimer()`.  You might use `nanosleep()` but you'd probably also need to use threads since `nanosleep()` blocks the calling thread.  That moves it up the complexity scale.  There are calls like `pthread_cond_timedwait()` that could also be used in a threaded program.

Your prototype `int run_motor_program(int serial_fd, char *label, timeout);` won't compile; you need to define the type of the timeout argument.  You also need to decide what your argument means - whether it is an interval or duration of time (the number of seconds to run the motor for before timing out) or whether it is the end time (the Unix time after which the program must be stopped).  There are various sub-second structures that you'll have to negotiate.  Your choice is likely to be affected by which system call you use for implementing the timeout.

Comment: I don't have a type defined for timeout in the prototype above because I'm still undecided about how to go about it.  Is there a "standard" or "more common" way of sending a timeout?  I know select() uses struct timeval loaded with the number of seconds/microseconds to wait.